# Debian: mounting cifs shares starts to early or timeouts at boot

Tags: linux, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am on debian bookworm and have the following entries in my /etc/fstab; at random, one of these SMB / CIFS shares are not mounted with an error of -112. I think this has to do with the fact that the network is not yet up - if I look at the output of dmesg, the first attempt to mount one of these shares is super early - OR alternatively, that these shares are on two NAS who both have HDDs that go to sleep - and so it takes a few (I guess 10-20) seconds at times until they respond again.

Once the system has booted, I typically find 3 of the 4 shares mounted and I can mount whatever share is missing manually at the command line without any problem.

I tried to mitigate both things with the _netdev and the handletimeout options, respectively, but no luck.... what am I doing wrong?

```
//192.168.0.12/share1 /mnt/share1 cifs vers=3.0,_netdev,handletimeout=60000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
//192.168.0.12/share2 /mnt/share2 cifs vers=3.0,_netdev,handletimeout=60000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
//192.168.0.13/share3 /mnt/share3 cifs vers=3.0,_netdev,handletimeout=60000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
//192.168.0.13/share4 /mnt/share4 cifs vers=3.0,_netdev,handletimeout=60000,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials
```